# Enable minimize to dock (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gsettings, ubuntu-dock, minimize

I am doing the following to enable the `minimize to dock` function:

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

But it doesn't work! Somebody knows another method?

Comment: Try running without `sudo`.

Comment: Try it with the the `dconf editor` rather than `gsettings`.   `gsettings` did not work for me either, but the `dconf editor` does it.  And, you don't want `sudo` as @pomsky says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for those who have the same problem (thanks to Martin W):

1. Install `dconf-editor` e.g. via *Ubuntu Software*.
2. Open it and go to `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock`.
3. Edit "**click-action**" and activate '*use default value*'.
4. Set "**custom value**" to `minimize`.